# Convert mysql date value to html5 date

Tags: php, jquery, html, date

Below is how i echo date using normal php date :

```
<input type="date" name="ref_date" value="<?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($stock['ref_date']))?>">
```

and the value(date) is : `23-11-2012`

but when i try to implement HTML5 date using :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.js"></script>
<script>
var $date = jQuery.noConflict();
$date(":date").dateinput({format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'});
</script>
```

why the value is different : `04-05-1929`

Comment: So what is actually served as the value of the input field?

Comment: sorry, already fix just change the format from date('d-m-Y',  to date('Y-m-d',  ..

Comment: Cool. Suggest you either delete whole question or post your own answer and accept it (big green tick).

Comment: you can convert the date when you select the data from the db with DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: Any reason why Y-m-d works and not the other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just change the date format from

```
<?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($stock['ref_date']))?>
```

to

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($stock['ref_date']))?>
```